# Is there a way to allocate memory for std::vector without calling elements' constructors?

Tags: c++, allocation

I want to process certain number of structures like

```
struct s{
  int f;
  int g;
  int h;
};
```

it would be convenient to use `std::vector`, but I'm afraid that

```
const int N = 100000;
std::vector<s> my_data(N);
```

will call `s::s` `N` times. I'd like to avoid that, initializing memory like:

```
s* my_data;
unsigned char* buff = new unsigned_char[N*sizeof(s)];
memset(buf, 0, N*sizeof(s));
my_data = reinterpret_cast<s*>(buff);
```

Is there a way to achieve this using `std::vector`, or should I write my own vector-like wrapper ?

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35496676/5267751). Come on, is searching that hard?

Comment: Your second snippet is UB btw.

Comment: BTW, if you cannot reserve() and pushback(), and you know what you're doing (beware accessing uninitialized data!) you may take a look at boost vector container, it has a ready made special constructor exactly doing that ...

Comment: @Jarod42 could you explain a little bit further? Is it being ub has something to do with memory allignment and padding bytes or sizeof(unsigned char) can differ from 1 or something else entirely?

Comment: A mix between Strict aliasing issues, and the fact that `my_data[0]` doesn't point on a **constructed** `s`.

Comment: You write `S* s = new (buff) S;`

Comment: You don't have to worry about performance of built-in constructors initializing plain old data structures. Have you measured the speed of your code before starting worrying? I doubt so.

Answer (score 3):

Calling [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) on the vector will increase the vector's capacity (i.e.: it will allocate the memory for storing the objects):

```
const int N = 100000;
std::vector<s> my_data;
my_data.reserve(N);
```

The constructors will be called as you insert the elements into the vector.